# JDBC Null pointer Exception thrown

Tags: java, jdbc, nullpointerexception

Hi I'm getting nullpointerexception at rs.next() or rs.getString(1)
it is really weird that sometimes rs.next() works fine and it throws nullpointerexception at rs.getString("PRODUCTCODE"),sometimes it throws npe at rs.getString("PRODDATE")
i dont understand why rs.getString() thows npe while rs.next() works fine

Here is my code

```
{ 
ResultSet rs = null;
String query = "";
BarcodeBean bi = null;
try {
query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE(GET_BARCODEINFO('"barcode.trim()"'))";

statement = connection.createStatement();
Logger.getInstance().getLogger().logInfo(query);
rs = statement.executeQuery(query);

bi = new BarcodeBean();

if (rs == null){
if(rs.next()){

bi.setUrunKodu(rs.getString("PRODUCTCODE"));
bi.setImalatMakineKodu(rs.getString("PRODMACHINECODE")); 
bi.setOperatorSicilNo(rs.getString("OPERATORID")); 
bi.setImalatTarihi(rs.getString("PRODDATE")); 
bi.setImalatVardiyasi(rs.getString("PRODSHIFT"));
bi.setSeriNumarasi(rs.getString("SERIALNUMBER"));
bi.setSirtTarihi(rs.getString("SIRTTARIHI"));
}
}
} catch (SQLException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
throw e;
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} finally {

DatabaseUtility.close(rs);
DatabaseUtility.close(statement);

}
}
```

Comment: you miss also a couple of + in the code that builds the query

Comment: @dfa: that's because it's a crosspost from here: http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5435361
Unfortunately the Sun/Oracle forums mangles source code when it's not posted with code-tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

probably you want:

```
if (rs != null) {
   if (rs.next()) {
```

or even better:

```
if (rs != null && rs.next()) {
```

Your test is simply wrong.

Comment: you meant if `(rs != null && rs.next())` probably

Comment: Your test is wrong as well. In harigm's code, rs can't possibly be null, when rs.next() is invoked.

Comment: In harigm's code, the first test is whether rs is null. So any calls to an instance of rs will automatically trigger a NullPointerException. Also, the && operator allows to test if an instance is null before calling a method on it.

Answer (score 3):

`Statement#executeQuery()` **never** returns `null`. The whole nullcheck is *superfluous*. The normal idiom is the following:

```
public Entity find(Long id) throws SQLException {
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    Entity entity = null;

    try {
        connection = database.getConnection();
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_FIND);
        preparedStatement.setLong(1, id);
        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        if (resultSet.next()) {
            entity = new Entity();
            entity.setId(resultSet.getLong("id"));
            entity.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
            // ...
        }
    } finally {
        close(connection, preparedStatement, resultSet); // In reversed order.
    }

    return entity;
}
```

Your **actual** problem lies somewhere else. This is clearly a misinterpretation of the stacktrace. To nail it correctly down, you need to lookup the line number of the first line in the stacktrace and point us the exact code at this line number.

Answer (score 2):

From [Statement javadocs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery(java.lang.String)):

> public ResultSet executeQuery(String sql) throws SQLException
>
> **Returns**: a ResultSet
> object that contains the data produced
> by the given query; **never null**

So, you don't need to verify whether `rs == null`.

The standard way to proceed resultset rows is:

```
while (rs.next ()) {
   doSmth (rs);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You made a wrong notation in if condition,

So change it as,
    if(rs!=null){
     ......
     .......}